# How to change Actionbar title only change font, textsize, textcolor

Tags: android, android-studio

I don't know how to change only actionbar title text font
[image]

this picture no font next picture font change together change bottom menubar font

i want to change only actionbartitle text font

[image]

At Result I want to change actionbartitle textsize, textcolor

I don't know what to touch in my code

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/black_overlay</item> //배경
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#00000000</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/godoroundedl</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using Java

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<small>YOUR TITLE</small>"));
```

or add this to your style

```
<item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
```

Comment: i use kotlin 
only use that code 
change is available?